# What could I do to reduce noise through a bedroom window?

Tags: sound-proofing

My bedroom is using double glazed windows with great performance on soundproofing noise made by cars outside.

Regarding little girls screaming and dogs barking, double glazed windows do reduce part of that kind of noise, unfortunately the remaining noise that passes through the window is not very loud but still clear and annoying.

What could I do next?

Comment: Hey people, please take this to the chat room

Answer (score 2):

You could add operable shutters outside, and heavy sound deadening blackout shades inside.

Even hanging heavy curtains would help.

Answer (score 1):

There are two kinds of “sound control” problems: 1) airborne sounds, and 2) impact sounds.

1) Airborne sounds (talking, tv, etc.) is the easiest to control.

2) Impact sound (closing doors, heels clicking on floor from walking, etc.) is much harder to control, but sounds like this isn’t your problem.

In order to control airborne sound various types of materials are added to inhibit sound waves from passing through walls, windows, etc.

Just as Jack indicated, adding items outside over the window will help DEFLECT sound waves and hanging items over windows inside will help ABSORB sound waves.

Also, adding a storm window (another pane of glass) that is A) a different thickness than what is currently in your windows, and B) installed at a slight slope to the other panes will reduce sound transmission, C) caulk perimeter of window, D) infill around window rough opening, and E) cover electrical outlets on the wall.

A) Using various thicknesses of materials will stop various wave lengths and reduce sound. Using 1/4 “ plate glass instead of the 3/16” sheet glass that is probably in your windows will stop different sound waves.

B) Installing the new storm window at a slight angle to the other panes creates an air space that varies. This will eliminate different sound waves too.

C) Make sure there are no air gaps around the perimeter of the new storm window by caulking the perimeter.

D) When windows are installed, they are installed in openings slightly larger than the window. This creates an air gap around the perimeter. If you remove the inside trim around the perimeter, you can access this gap and infill it with batt insulation or foam the gap to stop the transmission of sound. (Be careful not to use an expanding foam or it could crack the glass.)

E) Often sounds will travel through electrical outlets, because it’s the “weak link” in the wall. Be sure to cover all outlets, switches, etc. that are on this wall.

Comment: Re D, properly installed windows don't have those gaps, is that a cowboy method?

Comment: @SolarMike What does “cowboy method” mean?